# .bbl file not being updated

Tags: natbib, bbl

Hi I'm using TexStudio to write a LaTeX document and am having trouble with my references. I'm using the `natbib` package and it works fine until I add a new references to my `.bib` file. When I then try and cite that reference in the main document is comes up with "[?]".

Looking at the file path where I am saving it to, when I compile my document it creates several other files (`.toc` etc.) but the `.bbl` does not get overwritten. It stays the same as before I changed my `.bib` file.

How do I change this so that I overwrite the `.bbl` file when I include a new reference?

Comment: If I delete the bbl file in the folder, then compile again the references appear. But I don't want to do this everytime.

Comment: You need to run BibTeX so that the `.bbl` is created. If the `.bib` file changed it is a good idea to run BibTeX, you don't have to run it after every change to then document. There are tools such as `latexmk` that can do this automatically (there is also `arara`, but I don't know how that works). How do you compile your document at the moment?

Comment: I have re-tagged your question. You state that you are using `natbib` so `biblatex` isn't really relevant here. For reference [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `natbib` citaton management package does *not*, by itself, update the `bbl` file which contains the formatted references. Editing the `bib` file(s) also does not update the `bbl` file.

To update the `bbl` file, you first need to re-run LaTeX so that all citations generated by various `\cite` instructions are up-to-date in the `aux` file. Then (re)run BibTeX. BibTeX  consults the `aux` file to find out (a) which bibliography style should be employed, (b) which entries are cited, and (c) the name(s) of the `bib` file(s) that contain the unformatted entries. From these three inputs, and assuming that all information is provided correctly (i.e., no syntax errors and no missing files), BibTeX generates the `bbl` file as its main output. (Another output is the BibTeX log file, extension `blg`.)

Once the `bbl` file is created/updated by BibTeX, you need to rerun LaTeX twice more. During the first pass, the updated `bbl` file is read in and citation cross-references are resolved (and written to the `aux` file). During the second pass, LaTeX reads in the information about the citation cross-references to generate the citation call-outs in the format specified by (a) the bibliography style and (b) any options set by `natbib`.

Comment: That's great it it working now. Is there a simple way to do this each time I compile? I have found a way to do it from the windows command line, but having it automatically done whenever I press F6 would be great.

I'm using TeXstudio

Comment: @CallumHartley - I'm afraid I can't help you with TeXstudio-related questions. (I use a different front-end program.) I'm virtually certain, though, that it should be straightforward to set up a single keystroke-based action that executes LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more. You may also want to look into using [arara](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara?lang=en), a utility that can be programmed extremely flexibly for just such cases.

Comment: That's alright, I have searched further into this and found a shortcut built into the TeXstudio that updates the bbl file. Thank you very much for your help!